# "Le sachiez-tu", le savez-vous ?

Tags: expressions, conjugaison, registre-familier

Je trouve drôle ces nouvelles expressions gag qui font mode - enfin je veux dire *même*.

La dernière que j'ai repérée est *Le sachiez-tu* ou similaire *Le saviez-tu ?*

Ainsi : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikip%C3%A9dia:Le_Bistro/23_juillet_2013#Le_saviez-tu_.3F, ou [plein ici](http://www.bing.com/search?q=le%20saviez-tu&go=&qs=ds&form=QBLH&filt=all) et [là](http://www.bing.com/search?q=le%20sachiez-tu&qs=n&form=QBRE&filt=all&pq=le%20sachiez-tu&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=).

Est-ce que ça porte un nom cette idée de faire une conjugaison erronée pour faire *pseudo langage soutenu familier sympa* ?

Comment: *marketing, opération de com', copinage, blague (ou humour) [belge]*, mais ce sont là les lieux d'utilisation, pas une définition académique.

Comment: @Istao: *font mode* (dans votre 1e phrase) : Est-ce un syntagme officiel ? Que signifie-t-il ? J'imaginerais : *devenir à la mode* ?

Comment: Oui, j'invente des syntagmes... il semble que ça existe en allemand, d'après google : du Graaand journal Zeit http://www.zeit.de/lebensart/mode/2013-05/faire-mode ... mais allez savoir ce que ça veut dire en allemand :-)

Answer (score 2):

Si "saviez-tu" ou "sachiez-tu" est la (ou presque) seule occurrence de "mauvais français" dans un texte, je dirais que c'est simplement de la dérision: dépiction de gens ayant peu de culture, par exemple de gens "pas de classe", ou des paysans des bas-fonds, j'imagine.

Par contre, si c'est mélangé avec un paquet d'autres trucs "obscures", ça aurait tendance à me faire penser à un genre de [sociolecte](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolecte) ou même d'argot, un peu comme le [verlan](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan) peut-être?

Comment: Où de la poésie: _Dès que le vent soufflera, je repartira; dès que les vents tourneront, nous nous en allerons (de requin)_.